# what is the best way to transform a java Class into a php class?

Tags: java, php, class

I'd like to transform my java Class file intp a php class file. Do you know a good open source tool to do this?

Thanks you very much,

Bat

Answer (score 3):

As far as i know there isn't any good automated scripts out there that converts java code to php, best practice would be think through what you want to have done read the php documentation which is very well documented. And try to accomplish the same thing. If you hit any obstacles feel free to come back here and ask whatever it might be.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know any tool able to convert Java to PHP, but you may want to seize the opportunity of having a well structured source program in Java and keep a similar structure in PHP - as much as possible (by using classes, keeping the files segmentation, it'll help the conversion anyway)

Unless you have a pretty complex Java code (*synchronized* methods, Spring transactions, multi threaded access, data isolation...), or with heavy subclassing, or using an exotic framework, the logic itself should translate well from Java to PHP.
The templates should not be a real pain.

Regarding data structure, PHP usually makes the programmer life rather easy - basically you can make an `array()` from a `Set`, a `Map`, a `List`/`Array[]`.

Regarding data types, you have to be careful when PHP (not typed) automatically converts a fraction to a `double` if necessary (in Java `(int)4/3` is `1`, and `1.333...` in PHP).
Strings should be ok (implement `mbstring` in PHP - Java is utf8 by default)

And PHP offers so many functions that you should be able to find most of the necessary Java equivalent features.

Interesting project - I would be glad if you could edit your question and post the progress and how you finally could deal with the challenge.

Comment: I only want a script that help me to transform...I know that I'll have to check the class generated after that...

Answer (score 1):

Using a conversion script will result in bad or garbage code. To achieve a usable result you should read Java class carefully and implement in PHP.